The head moves without the hair, eyes and hat
I parented the bones to the head but it gives me a weird error, the hair, hat and eyes don't follow the head when I move the model. Any suggestions?


Parent the hair, hat and eyes to the head with Ctrl-P >Object:  Keep Transform..

I did but still moves weird, That's what I did in the first place.

Select the hair, shift select the rig, go to pose mode, select the head bone, Ctrl P > Bone.
Repeat for all others objects, choosing an appropriate bone (depending on how the rig is built).
BTW the head is parented to the bone, not vice-versa.

thank you, the head looks okay now

@Zoe Maya Animations if the answer is correct, mark it as such
